# How to store an html file in a SQLite db?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I am a newbie in android studio and I've been stuck to this problem. 
I am developing an application that allows the user to import an html file to the database and i still cannot find as anwer to this. Or maybe I did not research more but I hope u guys can help me.

Comment: probably you can havv a good tutorial on sqlite database,  and understand how sqlite tables are created and data is inserted in to tables. Generally htmls are not placed in these tables, but you can still put them as text.  For that you not necessarily require android studio, but you can download any sqlite editor and use for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to parse that HTML file and convert it to `String`. After that you have to individually parse data from tags and store them in database. It will be length answer, so you need to look into some tutorials online and take help of this website. Go step by step. All the best.

Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) is the Code of Conduct.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem, what you should do is first download all the html and save it in a string. Then, you will be able to save it to the sqlite db. 
So what you should do is:

1. Download the html and convert it to an string. You can use HTTPClient to do this task:

   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
       HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

   ```
   String html = "";
   InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
   StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
   String line = null;
   while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
   {
       str.append(line);
   }
   in.close();
   html = str.toString();
   ```
2. Create the structure of the sqlite db. I don't know if you already have done this, but there are many tutorials you can find in google like [tutorialSQLITE](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)
3. After steps 1 and 2, you just have to add a new entry to your database.

Comment: Hey. Is there a dependency that I need to download in order to use httpclient?